# Скрывать меню в мобилках при скролле Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, прокрутка, menu

Как сделать на Bootstrap в мобильной версии так, чтобы, когда нажимаешь на меню и скролишь, меню исчезало?

Сейчас, если скролить, то меню не уходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Меню не уходит, скорее всего, потому, что ему добавлен [класс `.navbar-fixed-top`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top). Если этот класс убрать, то при прокрутке меню уедет наверх вместе с началом страницы:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a></div>
    <div id="bs-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#header1">Header 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#header2">Header 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#header3">Header 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Main Header</h1>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>

  <h2 id="header1">Header 1</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>

  <h2 id="header2">Header 2</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>

  <h2 id="header3">Header 3</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Но можно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на любой из пунктов меню не уезжало, а просто сворачивалось. Для этого добавьте скрипт, который будет вызывать [метод `.collapse('hide')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-hide):

```js
$( '#bs-navbar a' ).click( function() {
  $( '#bs-navbar' ).collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
h2 { 
  margin-top: -50px !important;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a></div>
    <div id="bs-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#header1">Header 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#header2">Header 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#header3">Header 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Main Header</h1>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>

  <h2 id="header1">Header 1</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>

  <h2 id="header2">Header 2</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>

  <h2 id="header3">Header 3</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      $('.navbar-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
    });
```

Пример

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
$('#bs-navbar a').click(function() {
  $('#bs-navbar').collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: -50px !important;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a></div>
    <div id="bs-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#header1">Header 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#header2">Header 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#header3">Header 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Main Header</h1>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>

  <h2 id="header1">Header 1</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>

  <h2 id="header2">Header 2</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>

  <h2 id="header3">Header 3</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```